# Sockjs/socketio disconnect delay behind apache proxy

Tags: node.js, apache, socket.io, long-polling

I need to handle users disconnecting from my sockjs application **running in xhr-polling mode**. When I connect to localhost, everything works as expected. When I put apache between nodejs and browser, I get ~20 sec delay between closed browser and disconnect event inside nodejs. My apache proxy config is following:

```
<Location />
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</Location>
```

The rest of the file is default, you can see it [here](https://gist.github.com/stiv-yakovenko/c8c75750826818e99a14b95eb36354c3). I tried playing with  ttl=2 and timeout=2 options, but either nothing changes, or I get reconnected each 2 seconds without closing browser. How can I reduce additional disconnect timeout, introduced, but apache, somewhere in its defaults?

Comment: sockjs tries websockets first and if that is not available, then uses polling.  When you put apache between, you are only passing http so you are not allowing ws protocol so polling is forced.  What if you enable mod_proxy_wstunnel in your apache file, as described here... https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html

Comment: @bpursley, please read question carefully, I don't have any websocket data transfers without apache, because i have disabled websockets.

Comment: Do you realize that the only way to detect a disconnect from xhr-polling is with a timeout?  You just have to know what the client polling interval is set for and set the server timeout to something longer than the client polling interval so if you don't see any client come back to poll again after some period of time, then you assume the client must have disconnected.  There is no good way to get a timely disconnect with polling in all circumstances by the very nature of how polling works.

Comment: No, it is possible to handle disconnect, in nodejs for that you can register this callback: req.on('close',function(){console.log("byby")}). Even if sockjs inside has 1s timeout or heartbeat, I don't want 20 seconds to be added to it by apache.

Comment: @StepanYakovenko Do you have HTTP keep alive enabled?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm dealing with something similar. Though mine is a 60+ second delay and never got the constant reconnections you mention.

Comment: @kojow7, you are using nginx or apache only?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I am using Apache only.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have added my own question now.

Comment: @kojow7, This question is for long polling and yours for websocket. So posted a different answer for this one

Comment: @TarunLalwani Hmm, thought I was using long polling as I had followed a long polling example a few years back. Would it work better if I switch mine to long polling mode?

Comment: Long polling is a fallback mode for websocket, used when websockets are not available due to some reason. Use of long polling and websockets depends on the use case you have. See this article http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your Apache server is configured to use [HTTP Keep Alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) which will keep a persistent connection open. In that case I would try disabling `KeepAlive`, or lowering the `KeepAliveTimeout` setting in your Apache configuration to see if this solves the problem.

If that doesn't work, I would also take a look at `netstat` and see what is the status of each socket and start a root cause analysis. This [chart](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tcp-state-machine/) gives is the TCP state machine and can tell you where each connection is. Wireshark can also give you some information on what is going on.

Comment: @jfriend00 if you wish to add something do it respectfully this time.

Comment: Tried Keepalive Off and tuning KeepAliveTimeout 10, it doesn't help. Also if you look at ProxyPass documentation, keepalive option is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

In long polling the connection happens like below

```
<client> ---> apache ---> <node.js>
```

When client breaks the connection

```
<client> -X-> apache ---> <node.js>
```

Apache still keeps the connection open. Now there are two workaround to this

**ProxyTimeout**

You can add below to your apache config

```
ProxyTimeout 10
```

This will break the connection after 10 seconds, but then this break every long polling connection after 10 seconds, which you don't want

**Ping**

Next option is to ping the client

> **pingTimeout (Number)**: how many ms without a pong packet to consider the connection closed (60000)
>
> **pingInterval (Number)**: how many ms before sending a new ping packet (25000).

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { 'transports': ['polling'], pingTimeout: 5000, pingInterval: 2500});
```

Above will make sure the client is disconnected within 5 seconds of going off, you can lower it again further but then this may impact the usual loading scenarios

But reading through all the posts, threads and sites, I don't think you can replicate the behavior you get when connect to `socket.io` directly, because the connection break then can be detected easily by `socket.io`

Answer (score 0):

The 20 sec delay not in the apache proxy. I got the same issue, delay not happening in the local URL, but delay happening in global URL.

The issue was solved in the NodeJs itself. Need to send one time data from server to client to make sure it's initialized. This problem not in the documentation and issues blog at the WebSocket plugin.

Send a dummy message after request accepted in the server, like below.

```
let connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);

connection.on('message', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});

connection.on('close', function (evt) {
    console.log(evt);
});

connection.send("Success"); //dummy message to the client from server
```

Comment: the question is about sockjs, not websocket